# Use MVT to prove $(k+1) \cos \left ( {\frac{\pi}{k+1}} \right ) - k \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{k} \right) > 1 \qquad \forall k \geq 2 $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I want to prove
$$(k+1) \cos \bigg ( {\frac{\pi}{k+1}} \bigg ) - k \cos \bigg ( \frac{\pi}{k} \bigg ) > 1 \qquad \forall k \geq 2 $$ **using Mean Value Theorem**. My thought was to apply MVT to $f(x) = \cos (\pi/x) $ at $(k,k+1)$ but it did not seem to work.

Comment: That does not surprise me, since by plugging in $k=2$ we get that the inequality does not hold. It holds by replacing $1$ with $\frac{\pi}{2}$, for sure.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo mistake. Now it is corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x\cos \frac{\pi}{ x}$. Then $f'(x)=\cos \frac{\pi}{ x}+\pi/ x\sin \frac{\pi}{ x}$ Then by MVT $,\exists x\in (k,k+1)$, such that $$RHS=\cos \frac{\pi}{ x}+\pi/ x\sin \frac{\pi}{ x}$$ which is minimized for $\pi/x=0$ with the minimum value being $1$.Hence $RHS>1$.

Comment: Thanks!I had figured it out seconds before looking at your solution (Mine is the same one)